# How to create "N" Linked Lists?

Tags: java, linked-list

Is it possible to creat n LinkedLists?
I tried this...

LinkedList  l[]= new LinkedList [n] ();

I am trying to this in Java. Any sugestions? Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please look through the help files before you post. A [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. Also, please consider reading the help file on ['Asking a good question'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Beware of the answers listed below. When you nest lists like this the `equals` and `hashcode` methods are no longer well defined on a such a structure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are coming from C++?

You'll have to do that in two steps. First, create the array, and then, create the objects. Your approach is like doing it all in one step.

BTW, it is recommended to put the [] near the type. It clarifies when the type is an array.

```
    final int n = 2;
    LinkedList<Person>[] l = (LinkedList<Person>[]) new LinkedList[ n ];
    Person[] ps = { new Person( "Daisy" ), new Person( "Donald" ) };

    for(int i = 0; i < l.length; ++i) {
        l[ i ] = new LinkedList<Person>();
    }

    l[ 0 ].add( ps[ 0 ] );
    l[ 0 ].add( ps[ 1 ] );
    l[ 1 ].add( ps[ 0 ] );
    l[ 1 ].add( ps[ 1 ] );

    System.out.println( l[ 0 ] );
    System.out.println( l[ 1 ] );
```

Here you can find the complete code: http://ideone.com/Fv5psb
Hope this helps.

Comment: I Understand...but what if i want "n" LinkedLists of the type <E>?
Should i do something like this?

    LinkedList<E> [] l = new LinkedList[ n ];

Comment: Sure, but you cannot create an array of a generic type directly: LinkedList<Person>[] l = (LinkedList<Person>[]) new LinkedList[ n ];

Comment: I tried the complete code but when i compiled it this appears:
Note: program1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Comment: This happens when a program in Java creates a collection without generics, so Java cannot guarantee type safey, i.e. that no runtime exception is going to happen because type mismatchs (while the code compiles fine). This is due the creation of the array of no generic `LinkedList`'s.
Oracle docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayList of LinkedList as follows:
ArrayList l = new ArrayList<>();
You can add n or more LinkedList to this ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
    // Create your nested list structure
    List<LinkedList<Integer>> n = new ArrayList<>();

    // Create your linked lists
    LinkedList<Integer> ll1 = new LinkedList<>();
    ll1.add(1);
    ll1.add(2);

    LinkedList<Integer> ll2 = new LinkedList<>();
    ll2.add(1);
    ll2.add(2);

    // add your linked lists to the nested list structure
    n.add(ll1);
    n.add(ll2);

    // print out the data
    for(LinkedList<Integer> l : n){
        for(Integer i : l){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
1
2
1
2
```

As I mentioned in the comment, the `equals` and `hashcode` methods are no longer well defined for nested list structures.